# SpringBoot Application GCP Deployment Issue

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy a GAE SpringBoot application on GCP but no luck.

Getting Below Error:

> Uncaught exception from servlet
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.servlet.ServletException: Not running on Jetty, JSR-356 support unavailable at   org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:68) at   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:330)

POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.gcptest</groupId>
    <artifactId>gcptest-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <!-- Excluded for GCP Conflict, as gcp runs on jetty -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dependency for GCP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.48</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-6</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
            <version>1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-gcs-client</artifactId>
            <version>0.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
            </plugingcptest
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.properties</include>
                    <include>log4j2.json</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must convert your app to App Engine config. If you are using GOOGLE APP ENGINE standard, follow [these steps](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/appengine-standard-java8/springboot-appengine-standard#steps-to-convert-a-spring-boot-application-for-app-engine-standard):

**Use the WAR packaging**

You must use WAR packaging to deploy into Google App Engine Standard.
If you generate a Spring Boot project from [`start.spring.io`](http://start.spring.io/), make sure you switch to the full version view of the initializer site, and select WAR packaging.

If you have an existing `JAR` packaging project, you can convert it into a `WAR` project by:

In pom.xml, change `<packaging>jar</packaging>` to `<packaging>war</packaging>`

Create a new SpringBootServletInitializer implementation:

```
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
  return application.sources(YourApplication.class);
  }
}
```

**Remove Tomcat Starter**

Google App Engine Standard deploys your WAR into a Jetty server. Spring Boot's starter includes Tomcat by default. This will introduce conflicts. Exclude Tomcat dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Do not include the Jetty dependencies. But you must include Servlet API dependency:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**Add App Engine Standard Plugin**

In the `pom.xml`, add the App Engine Standard plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1</version>
</plugin>
```

This plugin is used to run local development server as well as deploying the application into Google App Engine.

**Add App Engine Configuration**

Add a `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml`:

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <version>1</version>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
  <runtime>java8</runtime>
</appengine-web-app>
```

This configure is required for applications running in Google App Engine.

**Exclude JUL to SLF4J Bridge**

Spring Boot's default logging bridge conflicts with Jetty's logging system. To be able to capture the Spring Boot startup logs, you need to exclude `org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j` dependency. The easiest way to do this is to set the dependency scope to provided, so that it won't be included in the WAR file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Out of memory errors**

With `Spring Boot >= 1.5.6`, you may run into out of memory errors on startup. Please follow these instructions to work around this issue:

Inside `src/main/resources`, adding a `logging.properties` file with:

`.level = INFO`

Inside `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml`, add a config that points to the new `logging.properties` file.

```
<system-properties>
  <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties"/>
</system-properties>
```

Comment: I was following the same post you are referring but no luck.
Some random combination of dependencies worked for me.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: @AnkitS can you share which dependencies? I have the same problem and cant seem to fix it. Spring runs locally just fine, however when deploy it cant find the servlet, exacly same exception